# Find the integral solutions to $ x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2y^2$

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, diophantine-equations

I am unfamiliar with this type of problem. How does one solve this and under what category of math does this fall under.

Find the integral solutions for $x^2+y^2+z^2=x^2y^2$

Comment: Well there's always the obvious $x = y = z = 0$...

Comment: It is called a diophantine equation,which is a term that describes equations seeking for integral solutions.It is a part of number theory and your problem is(possibly) a USAMO problem from the past.

Comment: Yes, it is a problem from [USAMO 1976](https://mks.mff.cuni.cz/kalva/usa/usa76.html).

Comment: This one is better: $$ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 3xyz  $$

Comment: I will try to solve it.

Answer (score 6):

$$ z^2 + 1 = (x^2 - 1)(y^2 - 1).   $$

The main thing you need to know from quadratic forms is that $z^2 + 1$ is not divisible by $4$ or by any prime $q \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ indeed not divisible by any (positive) number $n \equiv 3 \pmod 4.$

If either $x$ or $y$ is even and **nonzero**, let's say $x,$ then $x^2 - 1 \equiv 3 \pmod 4,$ not allowed.

When both $x,y$ are odd, both $x^2 -1$ and $y^2-1$ are even and $z^2+1$ is divisible by $4,$ again not allowed.

Therefore $(0,0,0)$ is it.